# php - Editing Data 1 Record Displayed + echoing a variable in a textarea

Tags: php, forms, edit

I have created a form for editing data stored in a table.

Retrieving form data :

```
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$id = $_SESSION['id'];
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$comments = $_POST['comments'];
$rating = $_POST['starrating'];
if (empty($subject) || empty($comments) || empty($starrating))
{
$message = "Missing Data " ;
header("Location: edit.php?message=$message");
exit;
```

Query for updating data :

```
mysql_query("UPDATE comments SET subject='$subject', usercomments='$comments', starrating='$starrating' WHERE id='$id'")
or die(mysql_error()); 
}
```

Displaying the data :

```
$id=$_SESSION['id'];
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM comments WHERE id='$id'")
or die(mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
if($row)
{
$subject = $row['subject'];
$comments = $row['comments'];
$starrating = $row['starrating'];
}
?>
```

I then display the field data inside a form :

```
<label="editlabel" for="subject">Subject</label>
<div><input type="text" id="subject" name="subject" value="<?php echo $subject; ?>"/></div>

<label="editlabel" for="subject">Subject</label>
<div><input type="text" id="comments" name="comments" value="<?php echo $comments; ?>"/></div>

<label="editlabel" for="starrating">Star Rating</label>
<div><input type="text" id="starrating" name="starrating" value="<?php echo $starrating; ?>"/></div>
```

All the data is displayed and changes are saved on submit but I only see one record, even if a user has  several records. Also I want to populate a textarea with the comments but this doesn't work :

```
<div><textarea id="comments" name="comments" value="<?php echo $comments; ?>"/></textarea></div>
```

I could create an inset class and style it like a textarea but would prefer to use a textarea. I have tried using print instead of echo but I still don't get any data in the textarea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$rating = $_POST['starrating'];
if (empty($subject) || empty($comments) || empty($starrating))
```

$rating and starrating is wrong

Answer (score 0):

`<textarea>` does not have a `value` attribute. You place the value you want to be displayed in between the opening and closing tags (it also is not a self closing tag):

```
<textarea id="comments" name="comments"><?php echo $comments; ?></textarea>
```